# Long Delay Before Curl Download

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I have a bash script that checks to see if a file exists in a web directory. If the file doesn't exist, it simply quits. If the file does exist in the web directory, it downloads it.

The script works correctly however, I just measured a 5:00 minute+ lag time before the script was actually triggered (Line 4) after meeting the "exists" condition.

Am I missing something in this script that is delaying the script from running?

**Bash Script Code:**

```
url="http://website.url/directory/file.txt"

if curl -f ${url} >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  bash some_bash_script.sh
else
  exit 0
fi
```

Comment: Where exactly is the delay? Look at the network traffic and at what curl is doing. It could be DNS, it could be that the server is slow to answer... Without any other data this is far too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `wget --spider` to bypass the long download delay with `curl`.

**Modified Bash Script:**

```
url="http://website.url/directory/file.txt"

if wget --spider ${url} >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  bash some_bash_script.sh
else
  exit 0
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also do something like this:

```
curl -s --head http://myurl/ | head -n 1 | grep "HTTP/1.[01] [23].." > /dev/null
# on success (page exists), $? will be 0; on failure (page does not exist or
# is unreachable), $? will be 1
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924422/how-do-i-determine-if-a-web-page-exists-with-shell-scripting

```
if $?
; then
  bash somescript.sh
else
  exit 0
fi
```

credit to @zneak

Comment: `if $?` will give you an `sh: 0: command not found`, `if [ $? -eq 0 ]` would work better

Comment: `curl -f` will attempt to return success if present and error code 22 otherwise, saving you the `head|grep`.